# Remove the close option on a batch file with a command, is it possible?

Tags: batch-file

I was just wondering if there is a code that can remove the "close" button on a batch file. (The minimize and expand buttons isn't important so it is ok if they will be disabled or will stay enabled) That is all. I can't seem to find any answer anywhere.
Thanks.

Comment: You want to remove the `close` button on a `windows console` window? This is not how batch scripts are designed.

Comment: You will just have to excuse me as I have just a little bit of knowledge with stuff like this. So there is no way to make the bat file, just the bat file, manually "unclosable" until it is done and closes automatically? I belive I have seen it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A batch file is nothing more that a script that another program must execute.

When you double-click a `.bat` file in Explorer, `cmd.exe` launches and "opens" the file, running the script. So your question is: can you remove the close button from `cmd.exe`? Good luck.

You don't want to be doing that. You should make your script NOT show a window to begin with.

If the window is shown, a user can always `Ctrl + C` to stop the script mid-stream.

There is a number of ways you can make the window hidden (also called "running a script silently"). See the following links:

- [Run a completely hidden batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file)
- [Solved: HowTo run a batch file without it showing](http://forums.techguy.org/dos-other/644932-howto-run-batch-file-without.html)
- [Eric Helps](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/invisible.txt)

Or just google for "batch file silent" or "batch file hide console".

Just a side note: if you have seen this behavior before, chances are that it is not a batch file, but another programming language, and probably not using `cmd.exe`. C# can let you make a console program app which you can manipulate the title, but even still you cannot change the control buttons on the window. It is simply not within c# or a batch file's scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing it up for me. I'll try to run silent.